# Adding an application to OpenWithList with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, registry

I'm trying to write an installer for an app I created.  I found a suggestion elsewhere that I was trying to follow and it mostly worked.  My app is now in the "Open With" list.  However, the app won't run at all.  Could it be that it's because the app is not being started in its directory, so it can't find the dlls?

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".xls\OpenWithList\docs.exe"; Flags: uninsdeletekey noerror
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".ods\OpenWithList\docs.exe"; Flags: uninsdeletekey noerror
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "applications\docs.exe\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; 
    ValueData: """{app}\docs.exe"" ""%1?"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey noerror

Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.xls\OpenWithList\docs.exe"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.ods\OpenWithList\docs.exe"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Classes\applications\docs.exe\shell\open\command"; 
    ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\docs.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my own registry, I see that the entries in HKCU contain a key 'OpenWithList', which contains string values of the program names.

The entries in HKCR however contain a key 'OpenWithList', which contains *not values, but key entries* with the program names.

Hope this helps.